# can we convert string data to IRestResponse?

Tags: c#, moq, restsharp

**String data:**

```
string restResponse = "{'name' : 'Test McGee'}";
```

Want to convert the above string to `IRestResponse` type.

**Because:** with the below code (in line number 3) I'm getting error:

> cannot convert string data to IRestResponse type.

*`x.GetRestResponse` returns `IRestResponse` type(which is from Restsharp dll)*

**Code is:**

```
var mockHttpClient = new Mock<IHttpClient>();

string restResponse = "{'name' : 'Test McGee'}";

mockHttpClient.Setup(x => x.GetRestResponse()).Returns(restResponse);  //line number 3
```

Comment: You can do `IRestResponse response = new RestResponse { Content = restResponse};` but note that response is not just content. It also has headers, status and so on.

Comment: Yeah I used IRestResponse response = new RestResponse { Content = restResponse};  and its working .Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As already indicated in the comments you can instantiate a class derived from `IRestResponse`

```
IRestResponse response = new RestResponse { Content = restResponse};
```

Moq can also be used to mock up a response using the interface

```
var mockHttpClient = new Mock<IHttpClient>();
var content = "{'name' : 'Test McGee'}";
var response = Mock.Of<IRestResponse>(x => x.Content == content);
mockHttpClient.Setup(x => x.GetRestResponse()).Returns(response);
```

Review [Moq Quick start: Linq to Mocks](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#linq-to-mocks)